# Backup picture using FreeFileSync

Tags: backup, photos

I would like to backup my pictures using [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/), I say pictures because i want to migrate both iPhoto and photos libraries till i figure which one i want to keep

I have my reasons not to use TimeMachine

So with FreeFileSync which folder should i be selecting as the folder to sync?

Comment: Consider also asking on http://www.freefilesync.org/forum/ for expert help on using FreeFileSync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To back up photos visible in Photos.app and iPhotos.app, select the folder:

```
~/Pictures/
```

Where `~` is your home folder.